# How can I access parsed dates by pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I parsed my CSV data with
`data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', parse_dates= True, index_col=6, date_parser = parser)`
Then, when I try to access the Time column doing something like data["Time"], I get a key access error. If I don't parse the data using read_csv and parse it instead after with `#data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')`, then my graphs don't automatically have the time on the x axis if I only plot y. My end goal is to be able to have the user select the time frame of the graph, and I'm having trouble doing so because I can't access the Data column after I parse dates. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

The sample CSV headers are these:

"Name","Date", "Data"

"Data", "05/14/2022 21:30:00", "100"

"Data", "05/14/2022 21:30:00", "100"

"Data", "05/14/2022 21:30:00", "100

Comment: Could you add a sample of your csv, including header (column names)?

Comment: Hey Bradon, I added the sample csv

Comment: if that's what your CSV looks like, then it could be why you're getting an error while reading the file. The CSV is malformed. There should not be any quotes or spaces in a CSV file. Also, in your code, you have `index_col = 6`. But the CSV you gave only has 3 columns. Are there more columns you didn't include in the sample?

Comment: Also, including the code you are trying to use to graph will help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Given a CSV that looks like this:

```
Name,Date,Data
Data,05/13/2022 21:30:00,100
Data,05/14/2022 21:30:00,100
Data,05/15/2022 21:30:00,100
Data,05/16/2022 21:30:00,100
```

****Note:*** no double quotes and no space after the comma delimiter*

You have several options to load the data.
Below is the easiest way if the data is a timeseries (all dates in `Date` column are different)

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Data.csv", parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")
```

The above returns a dataframe with the `Date` column as a `DatetimeIndex` with a dtype of `datetime64[ns]` and is accessed via `data.index`.

Resulting dataframe:

```bash
                     Name   Data
               Date
2022-05-13 21:30:00  Data    100        
2022-05-14 21:30:00  Data    100
2022-05-15 21:30:00  Data    100
2022-05-16 21:30:00  Data    100
```

You can then plot the data with a simple `data.plot()`.

If you want to filter what data is plot based on time, e.g. Only data on 05/14 and 05/15:

```py
data[(data.index < "2022-05-16") & (data.index > "2022-05-13")].plot()
```

or

```py
new_data = data[(data.index < "2022-05-16") & (data.index > "2022-05-15")]
new_data.plot()
```